# how to replace a value in a tidy data.frame as a conditional sum of others

Tags: r, tidyverse

For a `data.frame` similar to below (in my case read in as a .csv with very many variables), how to replace the value of say variable `a` with the sum of variable `a` and `f`, for matching dates? I've only been able to do it in long, clunky ways.

```
library(lubridate)
timestep <- c("10/31/1921","11/30/1921","12/31/1921","1/31/1922","2/28/1922","3/31/1922","4/30/1922","5/31/1922","6/30/1922","7/31/1922","8/31/1922","9/30/1922",
           "10/31/1921","11/30/1921","12/31/1921","1/31/1922","2/28/1922","3/31/1922","4/30/1922","5/31/1922","6/30/1922","7/31/1922","8/31/1922","9/30/1922",
           "10/31/1921","11/30/1921","12/31/1921","1/31/1922","2/28/1922","3/31/1922","4/30/1922","5/31/1922","6/30/1922","7/31/1922","8/31/1922","9/30/1922",
           "10/31/1921","11/30/1921","12/31/1921","1/31/1922","2/28/1922","3/31/1922","4/30/1922","5/31/1922","6/30/1922","7/31/1922","8/31/1922","9/30/1922",
           "10/31/1921","11/30/1921","12/31/1921","1/31/1922","2/28/1922","3/31/1922","4/30/1922","5/31/1922","6/30/1922","7/31/1922","8/31/1922","9/30/1922",
           "10/31/1921","11/30/1921","12/31/1921","1/31/1922","2/28/1922","3/31/1922","4/30/1922","5/31/1922","6/30/1922","7/31/1922","8/31/1922","9/30/1922")  

value <- c(0,0,4474,7027,32458,20702,29682,53150,20632,0,0,0,0,0,26569,22253,0,1894,25018,7119,0,2289,0,988,0,0,0,3869,8138,0,0,0,0,0,950,0,0,158,6028,2086,67193,
        4191,22303,5584,0,0,222,0,345,54,78,4545,2,4,0,0,186,113,256,4665,5756,78,34,20,323,3,0,0,9,354,299,8735)

variable <- c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","d",
           "d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d","d","e","e","e","e","e","e","e","e","e","e","e","e","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f")

df <- data.frame(timestep, value, variable) 
df$timestep <- mdy(df$timestep)


ExpectedValues <- c(5756,78,4508,7047,32781,20705,29682,53150,20641,354,299,8735,0,0,26569,22253,0,1894,25018,7119,0,2289,0,988,0,0,0,3869,8138,0,0,0,0,0,950,0,0,158,6028,2086,67193,
                  4191,22303,5584,0,0,222,0,345,54,78,4545,2,4,0,0,186,113,256,4665,5756,78,34,20,323,3,0,0,9,354,299,8735)

Expected_df <- data.frame(timestep, ExpectedValues, variable)
```

Comment: *"for matching dates?"* What matching dates? `df` contains only one date per row. Can you please include your expected output for the same data you give?

Comment: sure thing - just added. for the dates, there are six 10/31/1921s, six 11/30/1921s, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `spread` and `gather` from `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  spread(variable, value) %>%
  mutate(a = a + f) %>%
  gather(variable, value, -timestep)
```

Comment: Worked great for the example, but it's too slow for my actual csv with ~7000 variables - seems no need to spread all the variables if just adding two.  Curious if you or anyone might know any faster methods? Just in case for testing, I'm needing to things like replace Variable S4 as sum(S4 + S44) here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sSAhesUw0DWbUo1-hxVmJFlGBX4uUVlP/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this in base R using `by`:

```
df.res <- do.call(rbind, unname(by(df, df$timestep, function(x) {
    x$value[x$variable == "a"] = sum(x$value[x$variable %in% c("a", "f")]);
    x})));
head(df.res);
#     timestep value variable
#1  1921-10-31  5756        a
#13 1921-10-31     0        b
#25 1921-10-31     0        c
#37 1921-10-31     0        d
#49 1921-10-31   345        e
#61 1921-10-31  5756        f
```

Comment: thank you but I couldn't quite get it to work with my data without stalls or crashes. I wound up making two additional data.frames with each of the sum variables, adding them, removing the variable to be replaced in the original data.frame, and then rbinding. A few lines of code but it seems very fast.